# SQL Server find results within partition

Tags: sql, sql-server, count, ssms, sql-null

I have the following table:

```
ID    Date
-------------------    
 1    Null
 1    1/2/2020
 2    Null
 2    12/2/2020
 3    Null
```

For every ID which has at least one non-null date, I need to classify as 'accounted'.

Result set should look like below:

```
id    Date      AccountFlag
----------------------------
 1    Null      Accounted
 1    1/2/2020  Accounted
 2    Null      Accounted
 2    12/2/2020 Accounted
 3    Null      Unaccounted
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use window functions to check if the same `id` has at least one non-`null` `date`, and a `case` expression to set the flag accordingly. Window aggregate functions come handy for this:

```
select id, date,
    case when max(date) over(partition by id) is not null
        then 'Accounted'
        ese 'Unaccounted'
    end as accountflag
from mytable
```

`max()` ignores `null` values, so it returns `null` if and only if all values in the partition are `null`. This would work just the same with `min()`.